# Google Maps APIv3 very slow and large

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a website for a local business and have added a Google Map to the page using the API v3. I've been working on reducing the page size and load time and have noticed that Google Maps is by the biggest and slowest thing on the page. I'm still running it locally and don't have anywhere to host it currently, so all my related code is below.

Without Maps (Emulation for HDPI screen):

```
- Server Requests: 14
- Data Transferred: 1.5mb
- Load Time: 1.19s
```

With Maps (Emulation for HDPI screen):

```
- Server Requests: 82
- Data Transferred: 2.6mb
- Load Time: 8.08s
```

I am using the Google Maps API v3 to create the map.

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

With the script:

```
function initialize() {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-43.537061, 172.632426);
            var mapOptions = {
              center: myLatLng,
              zoom: 15
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              map: map,
              title: 'Auto City Services'
          });
          }

        function loadScript() {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' +
              '&signed_in=true&callback=initialize';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
            }

            window.onload = loadScript;
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or could do better in order to increase the speed of this process? I would very much like to make the load time and size much faster. I think I've got it set up to be asynchronous so that the rest of the page will display and the user won't wait up to 10s for the page to show, but it's still pretty terrible.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are adding the script element dynamically?

Comment: I think probably because that's how they did it in the tutorial I was reading. Would it be more effective to load it statically?

Comment: Can you describe your environment(hardware, network-speed). I don't think that you may reduce the amount of loaded data, but when it takes  1.19s to load 1.5mb(from your local harddisk) it may be that you'll need to speed up your environment.

Comment: Also note: there are also requests which doesn't affect the loading of the map(e.g.  QuotaService/ AuthenticationService) , don't include them into your calculations, they run asynchronously with a delay

Comment: @FinnLeSueur Loading the map script asynchronously as you are is highly recommended. I believe your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I'm running an Apache server using Xampp on a 2014 MacBook Air (OSX). It loads a whole lot faster when I enable the cache (I usually have the cache disabled in the Chrome developer tools during dev). The load time without Maps doesn't concern me too much as it actually loads pretty fast over my network for my IPhone 4. I'll have to rerun some tests tomorrow when I'm back on my computer and take those requests out of my calculation. Is there anything inefficient with my implementation of Maps at this time?

Comment: There isn't anything inefficient with your implementation. It's a default setup, for me the map loads in 3 sec  with a really not fantastic connection(about 10MBit download)

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll just put it down to sub-par internet speeds.